# I would like to know how to handle LSTM in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

We are trying to reconstruct a model using LSTM.

[LSTM Model Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6tvo.png)

In Pytorch, LSTMs know that 3D data is entered.

From the picture above, I am currently going to put it in the following shape.

(batch, lstm_num, dv_batch, dvector)

lstm_num: Number of LSTMs used

I am wondering if there is another way to process the 4-dimensional data using lstm_num as a loop or a tensor itself.

The original processing method code is as follows.

In the original, we get a
(batch, dv_batch, dvector) in 3-dimensional data.

```
for epoch in range(init_epoch, max_epochs):
    for i, (dvec_batch, prob_batch) in enumerate(data_loader):
        dvec_batch = torch.reshape(dvec_batch,
                                   (-1, dvec_batch.size(2))).to(device)
        prob_batch = torch.reshape(prob_batch, (-1, )).to(device)
        outputs = model(dvec_batch).squeeze()
        loss = criterion(outputs, prob_batch)

        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        adjust_learning_rate(optimizer, epoch)
```

Answer (score 0):

LSTM in pytorch takes input tensor with shape

- (seq_len, batch, input_size)

or if you've set batch_first = True

- (batch, seq_len, input_size)

The shape of the input tensor is not related to the number of lstm layers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  
I wonder if I should repeat the process in the shape of the input tensor or use it by modifying the 4-dimensional tensor.

Comment: You can split your sequences with arbitrary lengths, maybe what you want is split your tensor of shape (batch, seq_len, input_size) in N tensor of shape  (batch, new_len, input_size) and then loop on your N tensors and process one at time. You can't process this 4 dim tensor without reshaping it, it's hard to tell you a meaningful reshape not knowing the kind of data you want to process.

Comment: Thank you. I'll refer to it and use it.